# Why is my Jquery.ajax call triggering error event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I call the following jquery.ajax it always returns a fail. When I look further into the response it shows an ok status and 200 response.

Why is it throwing a "fail" event?

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "myurl",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: mydata,
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (data) { 
      alert("success" + data.slice(0, 100)); })
  .fail(function (v) { 
      console.log(v); })
  .always(function (v) { 
      alert("complete"+v); 
});
```

The data is reaching my backend url correctly.

Comment: Well, what's the error message?

Comment: There is no error message that I can find.

Comment: So how do you know the fail handler is triggered if it doesn't log anything ?

Comment: So `console.log(v);` is simply empty?

Comment: No it responds with the object and in that object responseText ="" and statusText ="OK" and status =200

Comment: Sounds like the `always` function, the `fail` function would log an error message ?

Comment: There is a message that is being logged to the console & fail is the only one that logs to the console.

Comment: Return something from the server. Ajax sometimes fails if there is no response text because jquery isn't getting the "expected" response.

Comment: I'll try that next. Right now I am always retuning a null. Thanks

Comment: It's expecting valid JSON to be returned

Comment: it seems no wrong code there.I assume the server res is triggering the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I made sure that the server responded with some valid json data and all is well.